# Does bending a piece of steel change the speed of sound in it?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics

Specifically, I have a student investigating sound produced in a helical spring (slinky) when struck. When it is struck it produces a sound that changes in pitch - from very high to quite low. Also, a slow, travelling longitudinal pulse can be observed to travel down the spring.

He suspects that the change in pitch is due to the fact that a longitudinal standing wave is set up inside the steel between the end of the spring and the location of the pulse travelling along the spring.

This would result in a standing wave of increasing length, therefore decreasing frequency as observed.

For resonance to occur, the (very fast) wave inside the steel must reflect and interfere with itself. For reflection to occur, there needs to be a change in acoustic impedance. Why might this happen at the location of the travelling pulse?

Comment: This is a good question +1. You can write an article for a  journal. If you add installation design and experimental data, then we can try to build a theory.

Comment: The speed of sound in solids is governed by things like the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus).  A slinky is kind of in between a wire and a rod, which means tension matters and so does the bulk modulus of the material.  I am guessing it changes based upon the amount stretched, i.e., the tension and some material properties change.